# How do I use my Java Class Library in Netbeans?

Tags: java, class, netbeans

I'm trying to better understand binary search trees, so I put together a Java Class Library for one in Netbeans.

It's all done, and I want to use it in something else I'm doing.

I built the class library, and created a library in Netbeans with the Jar. Then I added it to my project.

Now how do I use it?

Here's what I've got:

```
package bsttester;

import BinarySearchTree.*;

public class BSTTester {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree bst;
    }
}
```

There are no issues with the import, but

```
BinarySearchTree bst;
```

comes back with this:

```
cannot find symbol:
    symbol:    class BinarySearchTree
    class:     BSTTester
```

Comment: Why is your import package name the same as the class name? What is the actual and full class/package name?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The package and class names are BinarySearchTree. The import package name is the same as the class name because when I created the class library in Netbeans that's what it named everything. I'm really new at this, might be doing it entirely wrong.

Comment: So the full accurate name of the class is `BinarySearchTree.BinarySearchTree`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah.